# changed sa password but clients get bad password

Tags: sql-server

I reset the password for sa for ms sql 2008 R2.

I can login using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with the account sa with the new password.

However, when I go to update the servers (sharepoint) that uses the account, they get bad login (bad password) for sa.

I have tried multiple different ways to reset the sa password and restart the service, but so far no luck.

Why is it still giving me bad password outside the system, but not when used locally?

Comment: Are you sure it's using the sa user account? Check the SQL server's error logs and see if it shows other users trying to log in.

Comment: @KJ-SRS The SQL logs show the user "sa" as having the failed login. This also is the case for the sharepoint logs.

Comment: @KJ-SRS I have spent hours trying to figure this out. both Sharepoint and SQL show that sharepoint is trying to use the sa account and that login fails.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to a lack of experience on my end. I had to update the sa password in two locations. I had to update in the default database info, as well as the database specific (WSS_CONTENT) info.